# Navigation('DrawerOpen') is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am making an app following this tutorial:

I just did it exacly the same. It compiles but the button of the Drawer Menu does not work. This is the code where the button is:

```
    import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import ScreenOne from './TabNavigator/ScreenOne';
import ScreenTwo from './TabNavigator/ScreenTwo';
import { Container, Header,Left,Right,Icon } from 'native-base';

export default class AppTabNavigator extends React.Component{

    static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) =>{
        return{
            headerLeft:(
                <View style={{padding:10}}>
                    <Icon name ="menu" style={{fontSize: 24, color : 'black'}} onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')} />
                </View>
            )
        }
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <HomeScreenTabNavigator screenProps={{navigation: this.props.navigation}}/>
        )
    }
}

const HomeScreenTabNavigator = new createBottomTabNavigator({
    ScreenOne:{
        screen: ScreenOne,
        navigationOptions:{
            tabBarLabel: 'Feed'
        }
    },
    ScreenTwo:{
        screen: ScreenTwo,
        navigationOptions:{
            tabBarLabel: 'Feed'     }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 2.X of react-navigation you can't use the following code:

`navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')`

But instead you need to use:

`navigation.openDrawer()`

See also the [Drawer documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-based-navigation.html)

Comment: Perfect. How I can change this to work also in 2.X:    <HomeScreenTabNavigator screenProps={{navigation: this.props.navigation}}/>
@Perry

Comment: @HackFacilito What does not work in your HomeScreenTabNavigator?